# Creating centralized DB

Tags: ssis, ssis-2005, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have 2 databases(A) with same name in different servers( B & C). Both the databases have same schema. (sql server 2008 r2)

**Task 1:** Copy(transfer) both the databases into 3rd server (D) with the names (A_B and A_C).

**Task 2:** Merge both the databases into one database(A_D). (I don't know how will I handle keys)

**Task 3:** On daily basis I have to get data from servers B & C and put in centralized server D.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Ritesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ideas:

**Task 1:** Transfer databases by doing a backup an restore to server D.

**Task 2:** I think this will involve ETL processes and creating new surrogate keys in database A_D. Keep keys from original source in a data source id column. I think a [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement would be helpful.

**Task 3:** Leverage logic in Task 2

**Update for Task 2:**

Say a source `Table1` in database A and B has an key column named `Table1_ID`. In database A_D add columns `Table1_SourceID` and `Table1_Source`. Populate `Table1_SourceID` with the key from source database, and use `Table1_Source` to indicate the source database.

Use `Table1_ID` as the key for `Table1`, and is unique to database A_D. This will account for collisions for key columns in the source databases. Also, you can track the row to the source database.

Comment: For task 2: is it possible you can explain a little bit more. The main issue is coming both db has same tables and ids how to separate them. because it may be possible for some data in similar tables both can have same keys.

Comment: Thanks Mike... I will work on that and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

**Task 1:** Create destination Databases with no structures. I'd use tasks -> `export` function on the source databases with create structures option in SSMS. After export you will have exact copies in destination.

**Task 2:** In each table of `A_D` create a new key column (SurKey). It has to be a combination of values which will give unique values in the whole table. E.g. source table `abbreviation + PK column + date`.

For each table create two Data Flows in SSIS Package, which will load data from `A_B` and `A_C`. Put a `Derived Column` component, which will add a new column - SurKey.

In `A_B` DataFlow put the `A_B` as an abbreviation, `A_C` in the second one.

**Task 3:** Use Data Flows you created. Script a Job in SSMS, add it to the daily plan.

Comment: Just one qucik question... If tables structures in (A_B and A_C) are little bit different ..(means few tables have less or extra columns and different data types.).. Will this method work..??

Comment: Then I'll create one data flow, with two sources, add derived column with surrogate key, and then `Union All` component.